# C language, where is the segmentation fault?

Tags: c, function, segmentation-fault, strcmp

here is the function where im getting the segmentation fault

```
void searchcity()
{
    struct city *ptr=citylist;
    printf("Which city would you like me to search?: ");
    scanf("%s",searchedcity);
    //  printf("%s",searchedcity);
    while(ptr)
    {
        if(!strcmp(searchedcity,ptr->name))
            printf("name= %s, statecode = %s,population = %s,region = %s,zipcode =     %s\n",ptr->name,ptr->statecode,ptr->population,ptr->region,ptr->zipcode);
        else
            printf("sorry, couldnt find that city");
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }   
}
```

not sure what can be causing this to happen.

Comment: There could be many reasons why, but without more code it is hard to tell

Comment: There is not nearly enough code here to debug this.

Comment: is there anything that causes it within the function though?

Comment: @alex We need to see more code to figure this out without guess work.

Comment: Have you poked around this with a debugger to see if any pointers involved are `NULL` but shouldn't be?

Comment: What does the backtrace say?

Comment: @paxdiablo What do you think "bt" stands for in gdb?

Answer (score 0):

Based on that code <sup>(a)</sup>, here's what you need to check at a bare minimum:

- That `searchedcity` has enough space for the input <sup>(b)</sup>.
- That all the strings held in the `citylist` linked list are properly constructed (null-terminated).
- That all those fields in the structure *are* actually character arrays (or equivalent pointers) rather than integers (population, for example).
- That the list itself is properly built (no dangling or invalid pointers).

You do have *one* other problem, though nothing to do with the segfault.

Your code will print `"sorry, couldnt find that city"` for *every* node in the list that doesn't match your city so, if you have `New York`, `Moscow` and `London`, and you look for `London`, you'll get that message printed twice before it finds it.

A better solution (one of many variants) would be something like:

```
struct city *ptr = citylist;
while (ptr != NULL)
  if (strcmp (searchedcity, ptr->name) == 0)
    break;

if (ptr == NULL)
  printf ("Sorry, couldnt find that city.\n");
else
  printf ("%s, state = %s, pop = %s,r egion = %s, zip = %s\n",
    ptr->name, ptr->statecode, ptr->population, ptr->region, ptr->zipcode);
```

That way, the loop is responsible for either finding the correct pointer or setting it to NULL. *After* the loop is the correct time to decide what should be printed.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> That code itself seems okay other than the dangerous `scanf` but it does depend on quite a lot of other stuff not shown.

<sup>(b)</sup> In fact, `scanf` with an unbounded `%s` is a serious hole in your code that can easily lead to buffer overflow. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921) for details and solution. In any case, `scanf("%s")` is not a good way to scan strings with spaces in them since something like `Los Angeles` would end up as `Los` :-)

Answer (score -1):

Code below works, I did minor changes you can walk through it. Few small mistakes you had was your ptr->next was never executed due to missing bracket. The rest I wrote in the code.

Thanks hope we helped.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct city {
    char name[100];
    char  statecode[100];
    char  population[100];
    char region[100];
    char zipcode[100];
    struct city* next;
};

int main() // this is your searchcity function
{
    char searchedcity[100]; // make sure you initialize this. YOu haven't done it in the code you gave us.
        // Assume citylist is in your main function or initialized as a global var
        // I initialized it here for simplicity
    struct city* citylist = (struct city*) malloc(sizeof( struct city));
    strcpy(citylist->statecode,"statecode");
    strcpy(citylist->population,"population");
    strcpy(citylist->region,"region");
    strcpy(citylist->zipcode,"zipcode");
    citylist->next = NULL;
//end of citylist
    struct city *ptr = citylist;
    printf("Which city would you like me to search?: ");
    scanf("%s",searchedcity);
//  printf("%s",searchedcity);
    while(ptr)  {
        printf("while \n");
        if(!strcmp(searchedcity,ptr->name)){
               printf("name= %s, statecode = %s,population = %s,region = %s,zipcode =     %s\n",ptr->name,ptr->statecode,ptr->population,ptr->region,ptr->zipcode);
        }else{
                printf("sorry, couldnt find that city");
                ptr=ptr->next;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain the contention that `ptr->next` wasn't executed in the original code. Moving it inside the braces has no effect on the loop since it wouldn't be _in_ the loop if it were NULL.

Comment: @paxdiablo Oh, it has an effect alright ... it produces an infinite loop when the city is found. The loop is wrong, but that sure isn't the fix.